# How to give an illusion that a row is removed from JFXTreeTableView?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am using `JFXTreeTableView` and I want to delete a selected row from the table. I have tried many methods but none worked for me. Under given are a few methods that I have tried so far. `tableView` is a name for table and `student` is the name for `ObservableArrayList` of type `Student` class.

```
students.remove(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(0);
```

Now I want to give an illusion that a row has been deleted. I have also refreshed the table view but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
TreeItem<Student> selectedItem = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if (selectedItem == tableView.getRoot()) { // remove root, if you want:
    tableView.setRoot(null);
} else { // remove item from its parent:
    selectedItem.getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me the following errorincompatible types: Student cannot be converted to TreeItem<Student>

Comment: @AbdulMalik This is a `TreeTableView`, right, not a `TableView`?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve a behavior similar to your question. I used the following snippet, modified from [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) answer. It removes the selected item from the table.

```
TreeItem<Student> selectedItem = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedItem);
tableView.refresh();
```